# In Angular ng-bootstrap modal with template, close and dismiss buttons not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ng-bootstrap, ng-template

I am new to angular and I am learning by building.

I have a requirement to open a modal programmatically with varying HTML Content.

I have referred the first stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6amvy-pttrng?file=app/app.component.html) illustrated in this [issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2476) and created a ModalComponent (with selector called `<app-modal>`), so that I can create modals anywhere in my app.

Now, I use this component  with varying html content in a `<ng-template>` in my page.

The modal opens fine on clicking the button in the main page, but the close and dismiss buttons in the modal do not work.

I have tried to make a minimal example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1u4fo

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

I have created Global configuration of modals with let-c="close" and let-d="dismiss"

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<p>Welcome to {{ name }}</p>
<button type="button" (click)="openModal()">Click to open Modal</button>

<!-- Example 1: Passing TemplateRef as custom component -->
  <ng-template #modal1 let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <app-modal [title]="'Title'" [c]="c" [d]="d">
      <img src="https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/angular.png" height="100px" width="100px">
    </app-modal>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

modal.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title = `Information`;
  @Input() c;
  @Input() d;

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: @Sourav: I have created global configuration with let-c and let-d, can you check the solution

Comment: For anyone interested , here is an example with @Pawan's solution : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xzhq8

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.m1` with `ModalComponent` in your call to `openModal`.

According to the [API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api), NgbActiveModal only works when you pass in a component instead of the template.

> If you pass a component type as content, then instances of those components can be injected with an instance of the NgbActiveModal class. You can then use NgbActiveModal methods to close / dismiss modals from "inside" of your component.

Comment: m1 is a template, ModalComponent is a generic component which has ng-content in its body to hold that template. I need to load the modal with the HTML content inside the template. Hence what you suggest , wont give me the HTML content.